# Find different values between two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2019

I created two tables that have the same fields but may have different values:

```
create table TableA
(
    rowid int Identity(1,1),
    FirstName varchar(100),
    LastName varchar(100),
    Phone varchar(100)
)
create table TableB
(
    rowid int Identity(1,1),
    FirstName varchar(100),
    LastName varchar(100),
    Phone varchar(100)
)
```

I filled up the tables with some values to be able to test:

```
insert into TableA(FirstName, LastName, Phone)
values('JORGE','LUIS','41514493')
insert into TableA(FirstName, LastName, Phone)
values('JUAN','ROBERRTO','41324133')
insert into TableA(FirstName, LastName, Phone)
values('ALBERTO','JOSE','41514461')
insert into TableA(FirstName, LastName, Phone)
values('JULIO','ESTUARDO','56201550')
insert into TableA(FirstName, LastName, Phone)
values('ALFREDO','JOSE','32356654')
insert into TableA(FirstName, LastName, Phone)
values('LUIS','FERNANDO','98596210')

insert into TableB(FirstName, LastName, Phone)
values('JORGE','LUIS','41514493')
insert into TableB(FirstName, LastName, Phone)
values('JUAN','ROBERTO','41324132')
insert into TableB(FirstName, LastName, Phone)
values('ALBERTO','JOSE','41514461')
insert into TableB(FirstName, LastName, Phone)
values('JULIO','ESTUARDO','56201551')
insert into TableB(FirstName, LastName, Phone)
values('ALFRIDO','JOSE','32356653')
insert into TableB(FirstName, LastName, Phone)
values('LUIS','FERNANDOO','98596210')
```

If I do a select * on both tables there are rows with different values as the image...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/804ir.jpg)

So I need to insert into a temporary table the differences for each value that is not the same between the two tables and for each difference insert a row, the temporary table would have this...

```
create table #diference 
(
    diference varchar(300)
)
```

I'm trying to avoid using when or using a cursor, so I created this query to insert the differences:

```
insert into #diference (diference)
SELECT  Case
        when a.FirstName <> b.FirstName then 'The last name is not the same in A (' + a.FirstName + ') with B (' + b.FirstName + ')' 
        when a.LastName <> b.LastName then 'The last name is not the same in A (' + a.LastName + ') with B (' + b.LastName + ')'
        when a.Phone <> b.Phone then 'The phone is not the same in A (' + a.Phone + ') with B ( ' + b. Phone + ' )'
        End as diference
FROM    TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b ON A.rowid = B.rowid
WHERE   a.FirstName <> b.FirstName 
        or a.LastName <> b.LastName
        or a.Phone <> b.Phone
```

But it's only inserting in the comparison that have more than one filed different the first mismatch and I need to insert both mismatches or even more if has more and create one row for every mismatch.. any one would think a better approach to this....

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: `TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b ON A.rowid = B.rowid` Think again. This join logic is based on a significant assumption about the order in which rows are inserted into the two tables and ignoring the consumption of identity values due to errors or engine restarts. Are you absolutely certain you want to match based on identity column values in different tables?

Comment: Mmm interesting @SMor, so you think maybe to remove the inner join and just keep the where clause?

Comment: @Aaron well... the rowid is generated when a store proc does the insert of the 2 tables (as auto generated in each table), and both tables will ever yes and only yes have the same amount of rows...

Comment: Ohh got it, in the real world case scenario there is a field called idDocument that is the one who relates the involved tables in able to populate say table A and B, so the row id is just to have an order in the table to make a simpler approach to relate A and B (hope I didn't confuse you :) )

Comment: Why take a point from my question, if someone was able to undestand an gave a correct answer why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a generic way to handle two tables differences.

We just need to know their primary key column.

It is based on JSON, and will work starting from SQL Server 2016 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @TableA table (rowid int Identity(1,1), FirstName varchar(100), LastName varchar(100), Phone varchar(100));
DECLARE @TableB table (rowid int Identity(1,1), FirstName varchar(100), LastName varchar(100), Phone varchar(100));

insert into @TableA(FirstName, LastName, Phone) VALUES
('JORGE','LUIS','41514493'),
('JUAN','ROBERRTO','41324133'),
('ALBERTO','JOSE','41514461'),
('JULIO','ESTUARDO','56201550'),
('ALFREDO','JOSE','32356654'),
('LUIS','FERNANDO','98596210');

insert into @TableB(FirstName, LastName, Phone) VALUES
('JORGE','LUIS','41514493'),
('JUAN','ROBERTO','41324132'),
('ALBERTO','JOSE','41514461'),
('JULIO','ESTUARDO','56201551'),
('ALFRIDO','JOSE','32356653'),
('LUIS','FERNANDOO','98596210');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT rowid
      ,[key] AS [column]
      ,Org_Value = MAX( CASE WHEN Src=1 THEN Value END)
      ,New_Value = MAX( CASE WHEN Src=2 THEN Value END)
FROM (
        SELECT Src=1
              ,rowid 
              ,B.*
         FROM @TableA A
         CROSS APPLY ( SELECT [Key]
                             ,Value
                       FROM OpenJson( (SELECT A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES)) 
                     ) AS B
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Src=2
              ,rowid 
              ,B.*
         FROM @TableB A
         CROSS APPLY ( SELECT [Key]
                             ,Value
                       FROM OpenJson( (SELECT A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES)) 
                     ) AS B
      ) AS A
GROUP BY rowid,[key]
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN Src=1 THEN Value END)
     <> MAX(CASE WHEN Src=2 THEN Value END)
ORDER BY rowid,[key];
```

**Output**

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| rowid |  column   | Org_Value | New_Value |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|     2 | LastName  | ROBERRTO  | ROBERTO   |
|     2 | Phone     | 41324133  | 41324132  |
|     4 | Phone     | 56201550  | 56201551  |
|     5 | FirstName | ALFREDO   | ALFRIDO   |
|     5 | Phone     | 32356654  | 32356653  |
|     6 | LastName  | FERNANDO  | FERNANDOO |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

No need any additional table. Union the tables, since union only select `distinct` values you'll get unique rows. Any repeating rows with the same data, will be disregarded. the query would be like

```
select * from TableA
union
select * from TableB
```

Comment: Thanks @Osman but I already try that and did not work...